Not able to upgrade PHP8.3 on Amazon aws linux2 instance
I am trying to update php8.0 to 8.3 on aws ec2 linux instance but not able to update as aws not supported php8.3, i was trying with epel and remi but no luck, anyone faced the same problem or anyone can help to upgrade the same.

Amazon Linux 2 is based on Enterprise Linux 7 and Amazon Linux 2023 is based on Fedora
My repository support EL-7 and is known to work on "amazonlinux:2" images
See the wizard instructions.
But please note that EL-7 is 10 years old and will reach its end of life in a few weeks (in June 2024), so it is not a serious solution.
Also, there is not enough information about what is not working in your question.
